# Is it possible to limit docker daemon to only buiding images (and not running containers)?

Tags: security, docker

**Rationale**:

I am using Docker in Docker (`dind`) with `--privileged` flag in my CI to build images out of source code. I only need `build`, `tag`, `pull`, and `push` commands and want to avoid all other commands such as `run` (considered as root of all security problems).

***Note:*** I just want to restrict Docker's [remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) and not the daemon itself!

**My best options so far**:

As Docker clients communicate with `dind` over HTTP (and not socket), I thought I could put a proxy before `dind` host and filter all the paths (e.g. `POST /containers/create`) to limit API access only to building/pushing images.

**What I want to avoid**:

I would *never ever* bind mount the docker socket on the host machine!

---

**Update:**

It [seems](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/1.12.x/cmd/dockerd/daemon.go#L412) that the API routers are hardcoded in Docker daemon.

**Update 2:**

I went with my *best option so far* and configured an nginx server which blocks specific paths (e.g. `/containers`). This works fine for building images as it is done in the `dind` image and my API restrictions doesn't screw the build process.

*HOWEVER*: this looks really ugly!

Answer (score 0):

From a theoretical perspective, I believe the answer is no. When you build an image, many of the build steps will create and run a container with your requested command. So if you manage to disable running containers, the side effect of that should be to also disable building images. That said, if you protect access to running docker commands from a trusted user, and that user builds an untrusted Dockerfile, that result of that build should be isolated to the container as long as you aren't removing container protections with various CLI options.

---

Edit: I haven't had the time to play with it myself, but [twist lock](https://github.com/twistlock/authz) may provide the functionality you need without creating and relying on an api proxy.

Comment: Fair point! But limiting starting containers over API (socket/tcp) doesn't mean that the daemon cannot start containers internally for an image build. right?

Comment: The docker client doesn't send a `POST /containers/create` during a build though, the server manages the build process internally. So you can secure the external API endpoints without impacting internal server processes that might complete the tasks that you are securing.

Comment: @YanFoto have a look at [twist lock](https://github.com/twistlock/authz). I haven't had the chance to throw this in the lab yet, but it may allow you to filter requests without an api proxy.

Comment: Twist lock sounds promising! I should however find a way to integrate it with `dind` (and not my local Docker). If I get it up and running, I'll edit your answer (with permissions in advance!)

Comment: More than happy to have it edited if it helps solve your problem.

Comment: FYI: the `authz-broker` image is not on the hub and not that friendly to get it up and running :(

Answer (score 0):

Docker itself doesn't provide any low level security on the API. It's basically an on or off switch. You have access to the entire thing, or not.

Securing API endpoints would require modifying Docker to include authentication and authorisation at a lower granularity or, as you suggested, adding an API proxy in between that implements your security requirements.

Something you might want to look at is [Osprey](https://github.com/mulesoft/osprey) from Mulesoft. It can generate API middleware including authentication mechanisms from a simple [RAML](http://raml.org/) definition. I think you can get away with documenting just the components you want to allow through...

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: Yan Foto Docker API
version: v1
baseUri: https://dind/{version}

securitySchemes:
  - token_auth:
      type: x-my-token

securedBy: [token_auth]

/build:
  post:
    queryParameters:
      dockerfile: string
      t: string
      nocache: string
      buildargs: string
/images:
  /{name}:
    /tag:
      post:
        queryParameters:
          tag: string
```

Osprey produces the API middleware for you controlling everything, then you proxy anything that gets through the middleware to Docker.

You could use [OAuth 2.0 scopes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3) if you want to get fancy with permissions.

The docker client is a bit dumb when it comes to auth, but you can attach custom http headers to each requests which could include a key. [`config.json` can configure `HttpHeaders`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/).

Comment: This would double my effort with `nginx` as I should define Docker's API and run yet another middleware alongside `nginx` :)

Comment: You would only need one or the other. RAML's just a bit easier to read and audit when things get more complex.

Comment: You're right. I got it all wrong when I read "proxy anything ... to Docker". However, I *assume* running `nginx` (6MB in an `alpine` container) with a single config file is more comfortable than running and configuring a `node` server.